# What's the `When` condition for checking if the debug console is active?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-keybinding

I'm trying to bind `Clear Console`(`workbench.debug.panel.action.clearReplAction`) to a shortcut, the problem is what's the `When` condition for checking if the debug console is active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured this out:

```json
{
  "key": "ctrl+l",
  "command": "workbench.debug.panel.action.clearReplAction",
  "when": "inDebugRepl && textInputFocus"
}
```